# How to combine two MySQL tables with totally different columns

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, one with lots of records and one is empty.  They have right now totally different column names.  I want to merge them together as the start of a project to further insert info from other tables into the new table but can't figure out how to do it other than to manually add each column with its column_def.  Am I missing something simple?

Comment: And what do you want the result to look like?

Comment: There are plenty of ways of merging two tables with each other. Could you please be a little more precise on whats your actual concrete problem is ?

Comment: I-d just like to "append" the columns from table_2 to table_1, thanks.  One table has about thirty columns and the table_2 has 14 columns.  I can just alter table add columns with all the column_definition detail but I thought there might just be a simple command but can't find one.

Comment: @Dennis do you want to modify the definition of table_1 or do you want to create a temporary table by joining table_1 and table_2?

Comment: I want to modify table_1.  Then I can use an account_number column as a primary key to insert more data.  The account_number column is available from table_2 but is not in table_1.

Comment: You may use subselects in an Insert statement and use constants to fill the remaining fields with default values.

Comment: OK, I'll look at inserts with subselects that will allow me to essentially add columns to table_1 from table_2.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

An example to my suggestion you can perform something like this:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (column1, ....., columnN) 

SELECT (Column1, ...., '1', ColumnN, ColumnN+1) FROM table2 WHERE 1=1
```

Comment: will this take the column_description parameters from table2 or should each column_description be detailed out?  Thanks again.

Comment: You list every column of table 1 which has no default value in the upper part... and you need to arrange the columns of table2 in the order how you want to insert it in table1. Column names need not to match. But field types should match or you need to perform a type transformation. In addition you fill up the empty columns with constants like '1' or 1 according to the type of the column.

Answer (score 0):

this sounds like you are having a normalization problem.

there are not many models at all that are correct with dozens of columns on a single table.

if you could post your two tables, then i would be happy to help with a more normalized approach.  After that, you could decide on how best to populate the data.